# putting together a mysql query

Tags: mysql

There are two tables involved:

the first one contains a schedule in the following format (table: stimuli_schedule)

```
id      left_side     right_side     start_datetime
1       LS1           LS2            2013-05-14 12:00:00
2       LS2           LS1            2013-05-15 11:44:00
```

The data refers to the date-time when the left_side right_side items were introduced. For from 2013-05-14 12:00:00 to 2013-05-15 11:44:00 the first schedule record is active.

the second one includes activity records as such (Table exp8):

```
id     bee_id    date_time            choice    landing_duration
1      Green12   2013-05-14 15:35:31  right     5
```

I need to find out two things: (1) what was displayed on the left and right side at the time of the activity, and (2) what was the actual choice.

Here is what I have that doesn't produce what I need:

```
select * 
  from exp8 
  where exists (
    select left_side
    from stimuli_schedule
      where exp8.date_time < stimuli_schedule.start_datetime 
      order by stimuli_schedule.start_datetime asc
      limit 1)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide what is the currently result you are getting and what result are you expecting with more than 1 result so I can see the discrepancy and a possible solution to help you ? Also, do you have any connection between the too tables besides having to check it by the time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT e.*, ss2.left_side, ss2.right_side, ss2.start_datetime
FROM exp8 e
LEFT JOIN stimuli_schedule ss ON ss.start_datetime <= e.date_time
LEFT JOIN stimuli_schedule ss2 ON ss2.start_datetime <= e.date_time
GROUP BY e.id, ss2.id
HAVING ss2.start_datetime = MAX(ss.start_datetime) OR ss2.start_datetime IS NULL;
```

We have to join to stimuli_schedule twice, once to get the right date, and then again to get the full row that matches.

sqlfiddle is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/271b0a/4

Comment: Updated with a slightly better query that shows NULL if the event happened before the first recorded transition.

Comment: Wow this is amazing, thanks! I could not have come up with this myself. If I were to specify that only conditions where an LS1 or LS2 combination is displayed, does this look correct: WHERE (ss2.left_side IN ('LS1','LS2') AND ss2.right_side IN('LS1','LS2'))

Comment: Yes, that WHERE condition looks like it'll do what you want.